# AES GCM in C without EVP interface

Tags: c, openssl, aes-gcm

I have to write a **AES_GCM** encrypt/decrypt but without EVP interface. Is it possible to implement AES_GCM without EVP-* interface?

Comment: Yes.  Have you designed yourself an interface?  What information are you going to need to provide?  Are you going to demand all the data is available at once, or will you be able to build up the data as you go?

Comment: basic aes_gcm but without EVP_interface the openssl we have doesn't support EVP interface

Comment: The currently supported versions of OpenSSL (1.0.2, 1.1.0) both support `EVP_aes_192_gcm` etc.  If you don't have it, then either you're using an unsupported version or it was not compiled to include AES-GCM.  Are you sure it wouldn't be easier to upgrade to a version of OpenSSL with the EVP interface for AES-GCM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing AES256-GCM encrypt/decrypt in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670388/implementing-aes256-gcm-encrypt-decrypt-in-c)